# What vocal effects does Far Caspian use?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

I've been listening to Far Caspian for a while now, and how the vocals sound in their songs. It makes me want to try and imitate it myself in my own songs but I don't have any idea how to do it.

This is the vocal effect I want to try and imitate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fairly simple fx chain - firstly a tight bandpass EQ filter then dynamic compression. There's a bit of chorus/doubling going on as well.

Comment: thank you so much for this, I'll give this a try...